# Boost optional conversion from string to uint problem

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Could someone explain why the first conversion works and the second with optional does not ?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::string x = "16";
  uint16_t t =  (uint16_t)std::stoi(x);
  std::cout<<t; // prints 16
  
  std::string x2  = "16";
  boost::optional<uint16_t> opt =  (uint16_t)std::stoi(x2);
  std::cout<<opt; // prints 1
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::optional` is kind of like a pointer.  It's name, in this case `opt`, can be converted to a bool and it will be true if it has a value and false otherwise.  This is why `std::cout<<opt;` prints `1`.  To get the value out of the optional, you can "dereference" it like

```
std::cout << *opt;
```

and now you get `16` instead of `1`.